# Assert failure wifi-phy.cc

Tags: ns-3

I have set up two Access Points (APs) in my network in ns3. The first AP (AP1) is connected to two stations, and the second AP (AP2) is connected to one station. I've established a UDP flow between a station connected to AP1 and another connected to AP2.

The issue I'm facing is that the UDP flow is being interrupted, causing logical failures in the code. Both AP1 and AP2 are connected through ad-hoc Wi-Fi, allowing direct communication between them. I need help resolving the conflict to ensure uninterrupted UDP flow between the stations without additional socket communication between AP1 and AP2.

Additionally, the error generated now is an assert failure with the following message:

assert failed. cond="!m_state->IsStateTx () && !m_state->IsStateSwitching ()", +43.020044033356s 6 file=../src/wifi/model/wifi-phy.cc, line=1684

I'm curious if prioritizing communication between AP1 and AP2 over the UDP flow might be a viable solution. If so, what steps or configurations can I implement to prioritize communication between the two APs?